# Displaying of different ui-grid in different tabs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

```js
'use strict';
 
angular.module('Grid')
.controller('gridCtrl', ['$scope', '$log', '$http', 'uiGridConstants', function ($scope, $log, $http, $uiGridConstants) {
  $scope.gridOptions = {  };
  $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
    { name: 'ID', displayname: 'ID',  enableCellEdit: true, headerCellClass: $scope.highlightFilteredHeader},
    { name: 'Store No', displayname: 'Store Number',  enableCellEdit: true, headerCellClass: $scope.highlightFilteredHeader },
    { name: 'Merch No', displayname: 'Store Status',  enableCellEdit: true, headerCellClass: $scope.highlightFilteredHeader }
  ]; 

  $http.get('modules/grid/InputData.json')
  .success(function(data) {
    $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
  }); 
}]);
```

```html
<!-- <div ng-include src="''"></div> -->
<ng-include src="'modules/layout/header.html'"></ng-include>
<div>
  <div id="RghtsectnDiv">
    <div id="ShowCont_Area">
      <div><span>
        <uib-tabset>
       <uib-tab heading="Input">
            <div>
              <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid"></div>
            </div>
          </uib-tab>
          <uib-tab heading="Output">
            <div>
              <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid"></div>
            </div>
          </uib-tab>
        </uib-tabset>
      </span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

I called the grid for html,in that the heading that i gave in html(uib-tab heading) is displayed as tabs, but the grid inside the tab is not displayed.
In output it is going to the view of the grid and only the tab heading are displaying.
Check the snippet

Comment: Mostly unrelated, but seriously what is up with that HTML? You've got your tabs and lots of content nested inside a `<span>`. Spans are inline elements, they can't have block children! That being said, are you sure your `.get` call is succeeding? Have you tried adding a failure handler to see if maybe that's what's going wrong?

Comment: While using this as static code without views it is working.

Comment: .get call does not return anything..it is displaying array[0]

Comment: So... there's your problem. Your `get` call is failing. You need to define an error handler in case of the failure to return a grid, and then need to figure out why it can't get its data.

Comment: Thanks Frozen...I figured out the error.It is from my .css file